# How to show the last change commit and what are the differences for every file in a specific directory in my repo

Tags: git

This is my problem, in my directory I have many different files changed at different times and commits of course. Is there any command that can tell me what was the last time each file was changed and what are the changes?

Comment: You could just run `git log -n1` for each file.

Comment: Thank you @OliverCharlesworth but my question now is, how can I then compare each file to the file in that commit from `git lo -n1` so I can see the differences?

Comment: You could show the commit with `git log -p -- <path-to-file>`. This is really ugly/non-useful, but it might be along the lines of what you're asking?
     `for item in \`ls\`; do git log -p -- $item; done`